# Seeking suggestion about Left join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables t1 & t2. In t1, there are 1641787 records. In t2, there are 33176007 records. I want to take two columns from table2 and keep everything of t1. When I use left join with t1 to t2, I got more records than t1. I would like to get a similar number of records as t1 after joining. Please give me a suggestion. Here is my code:

SELECT t1.*,
t2.City
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN 
             t2 
            ON t1.ID = t2.ID;

Comment: You clearly have duplicates.  You need to specify what you want to do with them.

Comment: @Gordon. Yes, there are duplicate ids in each table. How to avoid those duplicates. Should I take a distinct id from both tables?

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate and choose an arbitrary value:

```
select t1.*, t2.city
from t1 left join
     (select t2.id, any_value(t2.city) as city
      from t2
      group by t2.id
     ) t2
     on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: but the duplicate id has meaningful values in other columns.

Comment: how to select two columns from t2, for example, another column Country.

Comment: it shows an error . unexpected identifier "t2" @ Gordon.

Comment: How can you get an `unexpected identifier "t2"` if the question says the table name is `t2`?

Comment: is there any missing in the code? it still says unexpected identifier "t2"

Comment: SELECT
  t1.*,
  (CASE
      WHEN t2.Code LIKE "%Chittagong%" THEN "CTG"
      WHEN t2. Code LIKE "%Dhaka%" THEN "DHK"
        ELSE
    "BA"
  END
    ) AS District,
  (CASE
      WHEN t2.Division =1 THEN "Bandarban"
      WHEN t2.Division =2 THEN "Khulna"
    ELSE
    "OTHER"
  END
    ) AS Devision_whole
FROM
  t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    t2.ID,
    ANY_VALUE(t2.Code) AS District,
    ANY_VALUE(t2.Division) AS Division_whole
  FROM
  t2
  GROUP BY
    t2. ID) t2
ON
  t1. ID = t2.ID

Comment: This code says unknown identifier t2 after group by column. Please let me know what is missing here.

Comment: @AbdurRahim . . . You can just use `id`.  When asking a question, you should use correct table names.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff......i use the correct table name. still shows the same error.